# Regex Split after 20 characters

Tags: regex

I have a fixed width text file where each field is given 20 characters total. Usually only 5 characters are used and then there is trailing whitespace. I'd like to use the Split function to extract the data, rather than the Match function. Can someone help me with a regex for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regex for which language? And must you use regex?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with string manipulation, rather than regex. If you're using JavaScript:

```
var results = [];

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i += 20) {
    results.push(input.substring(i, i + 20));
}
```

Or to trim the whitespace:

```
var results = [];

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i += 20) {
    results.push(input.substring(i, i + 20).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
}
```

If you must use regex, it should just be something like `.{20}`.

Comment: In C# at least, the following will produce an index error on the last iteration: input.substring(i, i + 20));

Comment: @Doug - I thought of that too. Tested it in [w3schools' JavaScript sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_substring) without any problems. It looks like `substring` takes the longest substring it can, somewhat similar to `IEnumerable.Take(int)` in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Split on whitespaces and get the first returned element. This is under the assumption that you do not have whitespaces within the actual data.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you must:

```
^(.{20})(.{20})(.{20})$ // repeat the part in parentheses for each field
```

You still need to trim each field to remove trailing whitespace.

It seems simpler to use `substr()` or your languages equivalent. Or in PHP you could use `str_split($string, 20)`.